# Remove the least significant bits equal to 0 in a BCD string

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am reading a file that contains a set of values represented as BCD (Binary-coded-decimal).  These values can be represented in different Byte-length.

For example, values for V:
V= 00 08 88 88
V= 10 00 00 00 08 34 00 00
V= 11 32 22 01 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
***Note***: spaces are not considered, I set them for reading purpose, the real value for 00 08 88 88 is 00088888.

My problem is that I need to remove the zeros from V.
the solution for the above should be:
V= 00 08 88 88
V= 10 00 00 00 08 34
V= 11 32 22 01 11

One easy way to solve my problem is to iterate and remove from the Least Significant Bit till I reach a non-zero bit.  What do you suggest?

Comment: What _is_ your problem?

Comment: If this needs to be an **`O(1)`** operation, please specify that.

Answer (score 0):

Right shift your bytes until `MyValue AND 0x01 > 0`

```
public byte[] ShiftRight(byte[] value, int bitcount)
{
    byte[] temp = new byte[value.Length];
    if (bitcount >= 8)
    {
        Array.Copy(value, 0, temp, bitcount / 8, temp.Length - (bitcount / 8));
    }
    else
    {
        Array.Copy(value, temp, temp.Length);
    }
    if (bitcount % 8 != 0)
    {
        for (int i = temp.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            temp[i] >>= bitcount % 8;
            if (i > 0)
            {
                temp[i] |= (byte)(temp[i - 1] << 8 - bitcount % 8);
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Code taken from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275572/bit-shifting-n-bits).