# Shifting a BitArray

Tags: c#, bit-shift, bitarray

I'm currently trying to shift a BitArray while keeping its length. Since there's no built-in method I'm struggling to build one but can't make it work, unfortunatly.

My initial BitArray code sets a length of 421 for the BitArray.

```
var b = new BitArray(length: 421);
```

Than, I'm assigning some values for testing. For instance:
    b.Set(0, true);
    b.Set(1, true);

However, I can't figure out how to shift the bit array.
Attempts:
 - I thought that I could convert it into long and than make the bit manipulation. However, long does not match my exact BitArray length, which results in errors later on when I apply bitwise operations on two BitArrays (my full requirements is (array1 |= array2 >> 20).
 - I tried to convert the BitArray into byte[], do the manipulation and return it (see [Bit shifting N bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275572/bit-shifting-n-bits)):

```
    public static byte[] ToBytesArray(this BitArray array, int startIndex, int count)
    {
        // Get the size of bytes needed to store all bytes
        int bytesize = count / ByteLength;

        // Any bit left over another byte is necessary
        if (count % ByteLength > 0)
        {
            bytesize++;
        }

        // For the result
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesize];

        // Must init to good value, all zero bit byte has value zero
        // Lowest significant bit has a place value of 1, each position to
        // to the left doubles the value
        byte value = 0;
        byte significance = 1;

        int bytepos = 0;
        int bitpos = startIndex;

        while (bitpos - startIndex < count)
        {
            // If the bit is set add its value to the byte
            if (array[bitpos])
                value += significance;

            bitpos++;

            if (bitpos % ByteLength == 0)
            {
                // A full byte has been processed, store it
                // increase output buffer index and reset work values
                bytes[bytepos] = value;
                bytepos++;
                value = 0;
                significance = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // Another bit processed, next has doubled value
                significance *= 2;
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    public static BitArray ShiftLeft(this BitArray array, int bitcount)
    {
        byte[] value = array.ToBytesArray();
        byte[] temp = new byte[value.Length];
        if (bitcount >= 8)
        {
            Array.Copy(value, bitcount / 8, temp, 0, temp.Length - (bitcount / 8));
        }
        else
        {
            Array.Copy(value, temp, temp.Length);
        }

        if (bitcount % 8 != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] <<= bitcount % 8;
                if (i < temp.Length - 1)
                {
                    temp[i] |= (byte)(temp[i + 1] >> 8 - bitcount % 8);
                }
            }
        }

        return new BitArray(temp);
    }
```

However, byte's length is 8, which can't fit well with my length too. The result is 416 or 424 (another byte) instead of 421.

- Finally, I tried the "primitive" way:

  ```
      for (int i = 0; i < bitcount; i++)
      {
          var lastValue = array[0];
          for (var j = 0; j < array.Length - 1; j++)
          {
              array[j] = array[j + 1];
          }

          array[array.Length - 1] = lastValue;
      }
  ```

I also check up SO (e.g. [BitArray - Shift bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684002/bitarray-shift-bits)) but nothing worked for me.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: not 100% sure what the problem is and how those links didn't answer it. You want an array you can shift left and right (I'll assume adding 0 when shifting) or a cyclic one (so if you shift right, and you have a 1 in the edge, it will move to the beginning? )

Comment: Are you encountering confusion between arithmetic (left-most bit sign-filled) and logical (left-most bit zero-filled) bit shifts perhaps? As per MSDN, the nature of the left operand (signed or unsigned integer type) determines which occurs under the C# specification. Note that the C++ specification leaves the prescription as implementation dependant. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx

Comment: @Noctis - I want a non-cyclic operation. I'm converting an implementation in C++ using std::bitset to .NET.

I don't think that this is the issue in my case since standard primitive types, such as int or unit, can't help me since I need custom bit-array length. My goal is to convert C++ std::bitset operator>> and << to .NET using BitArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not 100% sure what's the issue. Here's a naive implementation:

```
void Main()
{
    // Creates and initializes a BitArrays of size 7 (you have 421).
    bool[] myBools = new bool[7] { true,false,false,true,true,false,true };
    BitArray myBA1 = new BitArray(myBools );

    PrintBitArray(myBA1);              // 1001101
    PrintBitArray(ShiftRight(myBA1));  // 0100110
    PrintBitArray(ShiftLeft (myBA1));  // 0011010
}

BitArray ShiftRight(BitArray aSource) {
    bool[] new_arr  = new bool[( aSource.Count)];
    for (int i = 0; i < aSource.Count -1; i++)
        new_arr[i+1] = aSource[i];

    return new BitArray(new_arr);
}   

BitArray ShiftLeft(BitArray aSource) {
    bool[] new_arr  = new bool[( aSource.Count)];
    for (int i = 0; i < aSource.Count -1; i++)
        new_arr[i] = aSource[i+1];

    return new BitArray(new_arr);
}

string PrintBitArray(BitArray aSource) {
    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var bit in aSource)
    {
        sb.Append( (bool)bit ? 1 : 0 );
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note how bits are copied in the loops, and that the third `PrintBitArray` is done on the original input, not on the outcome of the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool[] Left_shiftBitArray(bool[] Array, int count)
        {
            Array = BitArray_LRotat(Array, count);
            for (int i=Array.GetLength(0)-1; i>=(Array.GetLength(0)-count); i--)
            {
                Array[i] = false;
            }

            return Array;
        }

        public static bool[] BitArray_LRotat(bool[] input, int x)
        {
            //bool [] temp= new bool[input.Length];
            bool[] final = new bool[input.Length];
            for (int i = input.Length; i > x; i--)
            {
                final[i - x - 1] = input[i - 1];
            }
            for (int i = x; i > 0; i--)
            {
                final[(input.Length) - i] = input[x - i];
            }
            return final;
        }
```