# Convert Python array/byteshift/struct to C#

Tags: c#, python

I'm struggling on converting an apparently easy code from Python to C#  as below:

```
def computeIV(self, lba):
      iv = ""
      lba &= 0xffffffff
      for _ in xrange(4):
          if (lba & 1):
              lba = 0x80000061 ^ (lba >> 1)
          else:
              lba = lba >> 1
          iv += struct.pack("<L", lba)
      return iv
```

I'm used to C# logic and I really can't understand arrays bitmask ...

Comment: Regarding this code, C# logic is effectively the same as Python logic. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `BitArray Class` in C# which manages a compact array of bit values, which are represented as Booleans, where true indicates that the bit is on (1) and false indicates the bit is off (0).

It offers AND, OR, NOT, SET and XOR functions.

For Shift operation, a possible solution can be found here:
[BitArray - Shift bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684002/bitarray-shift-bits) or [Shifting a BitArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596796/shifting-a-bitarray?rq=1)